# Was there a way to remove MULE Session on Mule 3.7 or later?

Tags: mule, mule-studio

On the previous version of mule we could aways add,

```
    <service-overrides sessionHandler="org.mule.session.NullSessionHandler"/>
```

for removing the mule session for http connector, but how can you remove the mule session for http request(newer version of http connector)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just try removing the MULE_SESSION header before the outbound call:

```
<remove-property propertyName="MULE_SESSION" />
```

Comment: Was there an alternative way for that or another implementation of  <service-overrides> on mule 3.7 and later?